# modifying excel formulas with macros or vba with string commands

Tags: excel, string, vba, formulas

I have an excel sheet with 100s of formulas of the following syntax

```
=SUMIFS(dollars,refcodes,A2,refDate,">=6/1/2016",refDate,"<=6/30/2016")
```

I need to change them all to the following:

```
=round(SUMIFS(dollars,refcodes,A2,refDate,">=6/1/2016",refDate,"<=6/30/2016"),0)
```

Can someone help me with a macro which would, on the active cell, insert "round(" after "=" and ",0)" after the last ")".

Comment: Do you mean just the one cell or all occurences in the sheet of the formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddRound()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            cell.Formula = "=ROUND(" & Mid(cell.Formula, 2) & ",0)"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Select your cells and run this.

Comment: What happens if there are other formulas in the range? Is it not easier to add in InStr test for something like "=SUMIFS(dollars,refcodes" ? I like the .HasFormula, haven't seen that before.

Comment: @QHarr meh... OP asked for the active cell, so I am assuming that they are going to choose the formulas they want, regardless of what formula is actually in the cells.  It is more than I should have given, as the OP showed no effort.  Therefore this is the effort I am giving.

Comment: Your reponse just made me chuckle. True.